# Does the tilde in CSS only select elements after a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create tabs with CSS using radio buttons and the `~`. My tabs work if the radio buttons are before the content containers but not when after.

I want them to be after since one of the tab buttons gets hidden and replaced with an actual button while it's selected and its really tough to do this in a generalized way if I have to take the radio buttons out of the flow.

So in essence, if I have this:

```css
#content { visibility:hidden }
#cb:checked ~ #content { visibility:visible }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb">    
<div id="content">stuff</div>
```

Is there a way to flip the order of the input and the div and still have it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "previous sibling" (nor "parent/ancestor") combinator.

In theory, if you are willing to use flexbox, then you could use the `order` property to swap the display order while retaining the DOM order. Here's the general idea (not tested):

```css
#container { display: flex; }
#content   { visibility:hidden; order: 1; }
#cb        { order: 2; }
#cb:checked ~ #content { visibility:visible }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb">    
  <div id="content">stuff</div>    
</div>
```

Normal disclaimers apply to browser support for flexbox.

By the way, the name of the "tilde thingy" is "general sibling combinator".